# Is Kamineko a jerk?

Tags: azumanga-daioh

In the last episode of the anime, Sakaki apologizes to it for trying to pet it all the time without taking its feelings into account. After that dialogue, it walks up to Sakaki and seemingly allows her to move her hand toward its head as though to pet it, but suddenly then bites her without any warning.

It also gathered a small horde of cats in order to attack Sakaki and Chiyo, but that ploy was foiled by [Maya](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtoJY.jpg), Sakaki's pet Iriomote Mountain Cat.

Is Kamineko really a jerk and a bully, or is there some deeper reason behind its biting?

[image: A biting jerk?]

Comment: I always guessed he used to have an owner that mistreated/abused him who resembled Sakaki, Which would explain his hostility towered her.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Kamineko, 「噛み猫」 translates roughly as "Biting Cat", or "Evil Cat".

As far as I can tell, the only real role for Kamineko is the running gag, so I'm pretty sure he's just a jerk.

Perhaps he can sense Sakaki's allegies to cats and that's somehow a trigger, seeing as he seems to single her out from the other girls to bite.